# Is it possible to send a form and a html request with same Event by Mootools?

Tags: ajax, forms, mootools

```
$('submitbutton').addEvent( 'submit', function(e){
      e.stop();
$('fuss').send(); 
req2.send();
});
```

trying to get this working but not  sure if it is possible and had no success so far.
Mootools docs  doesnt helped me either.
Will the multiple usage of  .send() work?
Do i have to specify the data beeing send for the html request or does it take automatical the data beeing send by the form ?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the documentation: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request#Element:send

This shorthand method will do a request using the post-processed data from all of the fields.

You can do as many requests in a specific event as you wish, as long as they're all asynchronous.

In your specific example it would seem you want to do two requests using two different methods, one with setting up a `new Request` class manually and the second doing it via the Element Method.

Comment: maybe i need  to be more specific:  i want to send the form and simultanously refreshing  a  container  with the stuff that is submitted.   something like  thx for your submission your data you send is  bla bla bla

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, I wrote a little example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsqx/1/).
Basically I think you don't need two request for your goal. Just override *onRequest* method to update the html.